# ImageMagick Runs from Terminal but not in PHP

Tags: php, terminal, imagemagick

Installed ImageMagick using macports and have the following path to convert:

$ which convert
/opt/local/bin/convert

Running the command:

```
/opt/local/bin/convert pollination.jpg -resize 50% pollination2.jpg
```

Does not work in PHP but the same command runs fine in Terminal and creates the image in the directory.

Is there anything I am doing wrong. Have not installed Imagick and would prefer not to.

Robert

Comment: Does it not work in some special way that could help to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Not that I can see. The new image does not get created even when giving an absolute path. However running it at command line does produce the expected results.

Comment: could you add the exact php command that you are using?

Comment: exec('/opt/local/bin/convert ' . $path . 'pollination.jpg -resize 50% ' . $path . 'pollination2.jpg');

Comment: where $path is my absolute path to my directory I want the images to be created and sourced in

Comment: try this exec('/opt/local/bin/convert ' . $path . 'pollination.jpg -resize 50% ' . $path . 'pollination2.jpg 2>&1'); redirect stderr to stdout and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issue. Apparently, it's caused by PHP/Apache not having the paths set properly. You can set them by adding this to the top of your PHP script:

```
$im_bin_dir = '/opt/local/bin'; //to get this, type "which convert" in terminal
$im_lib_dir = '/opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.9'; //do an "ls -l" in /opt/local/lib to find your directory
putenv('PATH='.getenv('PATH').':'.$im_bin_dir);
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='.$im_lib_dir);
```

To test, I added this to my PHP script (after setting $image_path of course). And, it generated the test.gif file!

```
$exec = 'convert logo: '.$image_path.'test.gif';
system($exec);
```